# Google Universal Analytics - Should campaign parameters be set manually?

Tags: universal-analytics

We use Google Universal Analytics on site example.com.

I've generated my site campaign URL : http://example.com/?utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=partnership

I want GA to be notified that URL was accessed with campaign parameters. How should I do it ? Is it automatically done ? I can't find mention of "utm" parameters in Universal documentation.

I think I should set each campaign parameter cf. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference

```
ga('set', 'campaignName', '(direct)');
ga('set', 'campaignSource', '(direct)');
ga('set', 'campaignMedium', 'organic');
ga('set', 'campaignId', 'ID');
```

and then :

```
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

It seems very much "complicated" for something that should be a common task when GA/campaign are used.

Any idea ?

Thanks for your help,

Philip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have created your link with the utm parameters, tracking is done automatically. You can find the reports under Acquisition / Campaign.

Answer (score 0):

After more testing : I have a source page which includes a destination iframe. Source page has GA and Universal enabled. Destination has only Universal.

Source URL contains campaign utm parameters, iframe URL is build with Universal decorate method, which gives : "http://myiframe/?_ga=xxxxx" (notice there's no utm parameters in iframe URL). Iframe actually sends campaign information, as it can be seen with Universal debug mode enabled in browser console "sent beacon" log.

Whath I understand is : it work automatically with decorate method if source URL contains utm parameters, but if it's not the case, information is lost in destination iframe, unless you manually add those campaingn parameters to iframe URL like : "http://myiframe/?_ga=xxxxx&_utmz=xxxxx". Campaign information is stored by GA in source cookie, but not transfered to destination.

Not sure, but one convenient way to add utm parameters to iframe URL (so, if there are not already in source URL), could be to use Universal decorate and GA pageTracker._getLinkerUrl to get all needed information.